# Space required laravel validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I want to store a full_name , and this full name i want always to be like this '**example example**' or '**name last_name** , string always contain a space in the middle'

`'full_name' => 'required|string|min:3|max:50'`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `'full_name' => 'regex:/(\w+\s).+/'`

***Update:***

By the way, I would consider splitting it into two fields like `first_name` and `last_name`. In this case, you could concat them in the back-end and problem solved.

Also, looking further into the future, there could be a situation where you want to pass first and the last name separately for 3rd parties and this is usually the case i.e. domain registration.